# Action Center Won't Open (ShellExperienceHost Crashes)

Tags: windows-10, crash, windows-10-v1903

```
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.18362.1, time stamp: 0x5cbddb81
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000006d3be
Faulting process ID: 0x224c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d51143b4a9c727
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
Report ID: 7d3fc6c9-e9d7-424f-b451-d31b15380202
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.18362.1_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

This works on other profiles but not my own, this computer is domain joined, I have removed my local profile and cleared my Active Directory one.

I've done an `SFC /Scannow` and it didn't fix it either.

I've also registered AppX packages using `Get-AppXPackage` and `Add-AppXPackage` (I don't have the one liner on hand)

To reproduce the problem if I click on the Action Center at the bottom right the mouse spins for a second or two then Event Viewer gets an event with the above message.

This is on a semi-fresh install of 1903 (I've installed VS2019, and VS2019 preview etc)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could outline exactly what steps led to this message and in what application or Window it appeared in. Also, what exactly do you mean by "removed my local profile and cleared my Active Directory one"?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! An edit has been proposed that looks like it might possibly be from you, but under a different username.  If so, you can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  If you have created a second account, that will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: Yep it was from me, I have two accounts can it possibly be merged in? I forgot about my old account and posted that from my phone thinking it was on this account